# Model with variable number of "properties" of different types.

Tags: mysql, database-design, postgresql

I would like to have a table of microscope slides, where on top of the basic id, name,date_created would each slide also have a number of editable "properties".

*Imagine one slide having*

- tumor_type
- dye_type
- description
- date_injected

*And some other slide could have for example:*

- patient_name
- treated_since
- description

I can't store all these in the *slides* table because I would like users to be able to chose used properties or add new ones if they wish to. Each property should also have a type, since some are integers, some text and some for example date and time and I would love to render a widget for them to simplify editing these values.

I planned to use **MySQL**, then I was pointed to use use **PostgreSQL** and its **hstore**, but that feels like a borderline experimental feature to me. Any suggestion how should I go about it?

This is what I came up with but it doesn't feel right to me:
[image: +-UML representation of what I am trying to explain here :)]

Also all this will end up in Django (Python) if it makes any difference.

Comment: PostgreSQL's `hstore` is far from being experimental, AFAIK.

Comment: Alright, I would also like to recycle already defined properties.

Comment: psycopg2, the preferred PostgreSQL driver for Python, has hstore support; see http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hstore` is ideal for this job, and isn't in any way experimental; it's been a part of PostgreSQL since 8.3 and is way easier to use in 9.1 and above thanks to `CREATE EXTENSION`.

The only real issue with `hstore` is that not all client drivers support converting `hstore` values to native maps or dictionaries, so you might need to get the properties for an entry as a table using the hstore sql function `each`, effectively converting the `hstore` to subtable result.

The only real alternatives I see are:

- A simple master-detail table in [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) style. That'll work fine, it's just a bit annoying to query, you'll be using a lot of `string_agg` or `array_agg` calls and it's lots slower than `hstore`. This approach is completely portable across database systems.
- Storing the properties as `xml`, which can be easier to parse from some applications and is sort-of indexable using functional indexes on `xpath` expressions. This approach is somewhat portable across database systems, in that it should work with any `SQL/XML` database.
- Storing the properties as `json`, which is easy to consume from most applications but is currently non-indexable and pretty opaque to SQL at the moment (expect improvements in future Pg versions). This approach is somewhat PostgreSQL-specific, but you can use a `text`/`memo`/`clob` field to store json in any database.

As for re-using properties that're already defined, that'a a simple matter of maintaining a table of known property names. If you want you can generate it on the fly using `SELECT DISTINCT skeys(properties) FROM thetable;` queries on the properties `hstore`s, but that'll be quite slow so I'd recommend maintaining a separate table.